# Unable to read config array in cake php

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp

I have a value inside config in config.php

```
Configure::write('key','value');
```

In App controller I can read it like this on beforeFilter function:
AppController.php

```
function beforeFilter () {

    echo pr(Configure::read('key')); //WILL OUTPUT value
    exit;

}
```

However when I insert an array into config like this:

```
Configure::write('key',array('value1','value2'));
```

This did not output anything.
So why is this happening ? I need a config array. Not sure what is wrong.

EDIT:
I have no idea how, but the above code has started to work now.
It is giving the output as

```
Array
(
    [0] => value1
    [1] => value2
)
```

Comment: I believe you need to add keys to the array and use `Configure::read` as: `key.key1` which will return `value1` (Check out the docs: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/configuration.html#Configure::write). Update me if it helped

Comment: Apparently nothing is wrong, is it throwing some error on logs?

Comment: Where do you set the value (configure::write)?

Comment: Ofir,  it's not working with key too. @ddos in config.php

Comment: you want try this in your controller Configure::read('key.value1');

Comment: it started to work, no idea how..  i didn't do any change

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at the documentation of [Configure::write](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/configuration.html#Configure::write).

**General stuff:**

Putting an array in the second parameter will be used to add [dot notated](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/appendices/glossary.html#term-dot-notation) configs:

```
Configure::write(
    'Company',
    array(
        'name' => 'Pizza, Inc.',
        'slogan' => 'Pizza for your body and soul'
    )
);
```

It will make `Company.name` and `Company.slogan` accessible in your config so that you can call `Configure::read('Company.name')` and `Configure::read('Company.slogan')`.

**Solution for your case:**

In your case you have to add keys to your array

```
Configure::write('keys',array('key1' => 'value1', 'key2' => 'value2'));
```

and access them in your controller by calling

```
Configure::read('keys.key1');
```

Comment: Then perhaps you could mark the answer as accepted, so that we can focus on other questions without accepted answers.